# AJAX form submission serialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have a simple form which collects first name, last name, and email.

The form uses AJAX to submit data to another site. When the form is submitted, first name and last name are recorded incorrectly and instead comeback with a serialized format. Email is recorded fine. I was unable to replicate the issue on my machine but all other submissions have the same issues.

I suspect the serialize() function is the culprit as the site the form is on is using jQuery 1.11.1, but the docs say it seems to support that function from v1 on.

This is what gets recorded in the form reports:

- last name - 5ad65afa9a4a6
- first name - 5ad65afa9a465
- email - foobar@gmail.com

  ```
  <form method="GET" action="https://www.mywebsite.org/submission-page" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="survey_5481">
  <input class="form-control placeholder" required="required" placeholder="First Name" name="cons_first_name" id="cons_first_name" type="text"maxlength="50">
  <input class="form-control placeholder" required="required" placeholder="Last Name" name="cons_last_name" id="cons_last_name" type="text" maxlength="50">
  <input class="form-control placeholder" required="required" placeholder="E-mail" name="cons_email" id="cons_email" type="email" maxlength="255" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&amp;'*+\/=?^_`{|}~.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*">

  <button type="submit" class="btn" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
  </form>

  <div id="form-submit-message" style="display: none;padding: 15px;margin-bottom: 22px; color: white; font-size: 20px; text-align: center;">Thank you for joining!</div>

  <script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {
  var form = $('#survey_5481');

  form.on('submit',function(e) {
      $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "https://www.mywebsite.org/submission-page",
          data: $(this).serialize()
      }).always(function(data){
          $('#survey_5481').hide();
          $("#form-submit-message").show();
      });

      return false;
  });
  }); 
  </script>
  ```

Comment: Ignore the ajax bit to simplify this. Can you use console.log on the output of serialize, and tell us the input data? `form.on('submit',function(e) { console.log($(this).serialize()) });`

Comment: "I suspect"...what's stopping you proving it? Either do as noface says, or look in your Network tab and find the ajax request, and look at what actually gets submitted. Note that this would really be better off as a POST, since right now your user's details and email address will be logged anywhere that logs URL visits e.g. webserver logs or potentially browsing history, since with a GET they end up forming part of the URL string, which is potentially a security risk. With a POST they are of course transmitted in the body and therefore not logged in the same way.

Comment: P.S. What did you input on the form, in order to get that data in your reports? Funny that only two of the three fields are affected?

Comment: To clarify a few things posted above:

- the console.log returned "cons_first_name=Test2&cons_last_name=testlname&cons_email=test22%40gmail.com"
- i changed the POST to GET as a test to see if that would change anything (it didnt)
- all of my inputs while doing tests are coming thru just fine...its users outside of my environment which seem to have these serialized names

Comment: I performed what @Noface recommended. The outputs where correct. Are you sure the problem is client side?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/a5qfkpay/ allows us - and you - to demonstrate that .serialize() is almost certainly not to blame here. It uses jQuery 1.9, so even older, and it's no problem. The values are serialised to what you'd expect them to be

Comment: @KarlGraham I am fairly certain problem is client side as this form is now submitting data to my own page prior to submission on the final form. The reason for this was to collect what was being passed on the client side. Same issues occurred with the serialization of first and last name only

Comment: "now submitting data to my own page prior to submission on the final form"...can you clarify what you mean by this? Is this a different instance of the application to the one where the problem is occurring? Or a different setup of the form? Or both? It's usually better not to change extra things if you're trying to reproduce an issue. As it stands, this question is not really answerable because we don't have enough info here to reproduce the error.

Comment: Do you know if only certain users experience this? Perhaps your server logs can tell you what browser they were using (based on the user-agent), and see if there's any pattern there. Since they're GETs, you'd also see the values submitted on the querystring, so you'll see exactly what the clients sent you, and whether it was correct at the time it first arrived at your server, or not.

Comment: @ADyson this is the same instance of which the problem is occurring. i was referencing what i did prior to the initial post. Right now this is how its set up: form -> GET form data -> submit form data. 

I put a "middle man" to get the form data to see if it was server or client side issues

Comment: @ADyson most users experience this. I did not capture browser or OS (although that will be a next step) yet. The biggest problem is the site which this form is on is on a client site which I do not have access to. I want to limit the back and forth but not sure if theres a way around it at this point since I cant replicate the issue

Comment: " this is the same instance of which the problem is occurring." .... "The biggest problem is the site which this form is on is on a client site which I do not have access to." . Which is it? If you don't have access to it, then how can it be the same instance you're using to test with? Not sure I understand what you're saying.

Comment: @ADyson I have to send code to the client to put on their site to test. So its not readily available and will take some time to update

Comment: Is it just the server-side you can't access. Can you access the URL of front-end of it, so you can send some test values yourself on the real form, and watch the ajax to see how it serialises it? TBH though if almost all users experience this, and we have already shown that serialize() does not appear to do anything odd, and only two of the fields are affected, I really strongly think it's far more likely to be something wrong in the server-side code somewhere. You say this strange output is on some "reports"...so does that imply you don't even know if it's like that in the database?

Comment: @ADyson once the form submits, the data is sent via client side script to my own PHP page which GETs the serialized data and saves the values to my own DB prior to resubmitting the data to be processed on the final form. What im getting initially from the client side script is already serialized although our tests and console.log show that the fname and lnames are not serialized

Comment: "the fname and lnames are not serialized"... I think we have got two different definitions of "serialise" here... ".serialize()" serialises data into a format suitable for transmission in a HTTP request as a set of parameters. So by that definition, _all_ the data gets serialised. But I think by "serialisation" you are actually referring to this business of getting things like "5ad65afa9a4a6" back? What kind of serialisation do you believe this to be? What format is it in, do you know? I don't recognise it, just looks like junk to me. It's certainly not the result of serialisation/urlencoding

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
$("#survey_5481").submit(function(event){
event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action 
var post_url = $(this).attr("action"); //get form action url
var form_data = $(this).serialize(); //Encode form elements for submission

$.get( post_url, form_data, function( response ) {
  $("#form-submit-message").html( response );
});
});
```

Comment: it would be better to explain _why_ you think this solves the problem